# custom cell reference in ag-grid in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

i created ag-grid table using react js after that passing json data to table after passing data table look like this[image]

Now i want to customize status column by some different color if status **high** use **red** if **low** use **green** **else** use **yellow**

Final output i want like this

[image]

How resolve this using react js for more code reference [click here](https://github.com/Chuttyboy/grid-api-call/blob/master/src/App.js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can conditionally apply styles to cells based on their values. Here are some ways taken from this doc [example](https://ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/cell-styles/#example-cell-styling) on styling cells.

```
{
        
        field: 'status',
        cellClass: params => {
            return params.value === 'high' 
                     ? 'my-class-red' 
                     : params.value === 'low' 
                        ? 'my-class-green'
                        :  'my-class-yellow';
        },
    },
```